# If $a_n \geq b_n$ and $b_n \to 0$, does $\liminf a_n \geq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

Let sequences $a_n \geq b_k$ where $b_n \to 0$.

Does $\liminf a_n \geq 0$?

Definitely $a_n$ need not tend to $0$. I don't know if its limsup or liminf can be greater than to zero though.

Comment: Sorry I made a misstake.

Comment: If $(a_{n_k})_k$ is a convergent subsequence of $(a_n)$, its limit must be non-negative (comparing with $(b_{n_k})_k\rightarrow0$).

Comment: But why should $a_n$ have a convergent subsequence? We don't know that $a_n$ is bounded.

Comment: If $(a_n)$ has no convergent subsequence, what is its $\liminf$?

Comment: Oh i see. It has to be $\infty$, can't be $-\infty$ because of $a_n \geq b_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = 0 \Rightarrow \liminf b_n = 0.$$

Comment: So if I take $liminf$ on both sides of my inequality this gives the result. But why can't I take $\limsup$ instead?

Comment: Why would you take $\limsup$ if you want to show something about $\liminf a_n$?

Comment: Nevermind, your argument also give $\limsup a_n \geq 0$, but this is not a problem.